# Beginner with parallel arrays in python

Tags: python

I've been stuck with program for almost a week. What i'm trying to do create a program that inputs the names of salespersons and their total sales for the month in two parallel arrays (Names and Sales) and determine which salesperson has the greatest sales(Max)

```
Names = [" "]*3
Sales = [0]*3
Index = 0
Max = 0

K = 0

Names[K] = input("Enter salesperson's name and monthly sales: (To Exit enter   * or 0)")
Sales[K] = int(input("Enter monthly sales:"))

while (Names[K] !="*"):
    if Sales[K] > Max :
       index = K
       Max = Sales[index]

       K = K + 1


print("Max sales for the month: ",Max)
print("Salesperson: ",(Names[Index]))
```

It doesn't prompt the user 3 times for the Name and salary it instead just asks once and i get this error:

```
Enter salesperson's name and monthly sales: (To Exit enter * or 0)jon Enter monthly sales:3 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\sales.py", line 18, in <module> while (Names[K] !="*"): 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: it doesn't prompt the user 3 times for the Name and salary it instead just asks once and i get this error:::   Enter salesperson's name and monthly sales: (To Exit enter * or 0)jon
Enter monthly sales:3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\sales.py", line 18, in <module>
    while (Names[K] !="*"):
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of having 'parallel arrays' you put the names and sales figures into a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  Here is what it looks like you need:

```
totals = {}
name = input("enter name: ")
while name:
    sales = int(input("enter sales: "))
    totals[name] = sales
    name = input("enter name: ")
```

This code will also continue accepting new names until you enter a blank name.

From here you should probably use pythons [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class like this:

```
# move this import to the top of the file
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(totals)
max_seller = max(c)
print("Max sales for the month", totals[max_seller])
print("Salesperson:", max_seller)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only prompts the user once for input before the beginning of the loop, so the loop will never end unless * is entered the first time.  Since you bounded your arrays as size 3, you get an error when K is larger than 2.  In Python you can use the append method to increase the size of your lists, but if you want them to be like fixed length arrays then you need to include something in your code to catch when the user fails to enter * before K becomes equal to the array size.